# Access "bad sites" list from embedded Chromium?

Tags: delphi, google-chrome, chromium, delphi-6

Embedded Chromium does not have the same protection as stand-alone Chrome does when it comes to warning users about "bad sites".  Users of Chrome are familiar with the warning screen that comes up when you attempt to navigate to a web site that Google has detected malware or other nefarious web elements on.  However, repeating this operation in embedded Chromium does not lead to the warning screen.  Does anyone know how to reproduce this capability so I can add it to my embedded Chromimum project (in Delphi 6 Pro)?  If someone has "traced out" the web calls necessary to recreate this capability I'd like to know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check a URL against the Google lists of suspected phishing and malware pages using the [`Google Safe Browsing API`](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/). to see how access this API from delphi check this article [`Using the Google Safe Browsing API from Delphi`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/using-the-google-safe-browsing-api-from-delphi/) from here you can integrate the code of the article inside of your own project.